# Does Gauss' Law Impose Limitations on Externally Generated Fields?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Gauss' law states that the electric field flux through a closed surface without any charges on the inside is zero. In introductory physics, it is stated that this is true for both fields generated from within the surface and those fields whose sources are external to the surface. Examples of external fields are given, such as a uniform electric field (the flux exiting a closed surface will cancel out the flux entering). We generally are not told where these external fields come from; fields configurations are simply posited and shown to obey Gauss' law.

But taking this approach, couldn't I posit a field which has a constant value for $x<0$, and 0 for $x>0$? If I then put a sphere at the origin the net flux will not be zero. So how can this be consistent with Gauss' law? Does Gauss' law tell us what sort of external fields are physically possible, and those which are not?

Comment: It tells us that there has to be charge at $x=0$ for that field configuration to exist.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, $$\vec{E}(x,y,z)=\sigma \vec{e}_x \Theta(-x) \;\Rightarrow \;{\rm div} \vec{E}(x,y,z) = \sigma \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Theta(-x)= - \sigma \delta(x) \equiv \rho(x,y,z), $$ i.e. constant surface-charge density $-\sigma$ in the $y$-$z$ plane $x=0$.